# Auto increment ID reversed and not organized issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

This might sound silly and it doesn't affect my code but out of curiosity, what causes the auto increment "ID" to be reversed like that and not increments correctly?

[image]

The structure:
[image]

Comment: There is no reason to assume that the rows are being displayed in the order they were inserted - I assume thats what you are referring to? In SQL Server rows are only ordered in a known manner when there is an `order by` clause.

Comment: did u change the clustred index ?

Comment: @Ajt  no i didn't

Comment: @DaleK  but all the other table and this specific table used to be ordered incrementally by this ID. why this sudden change in behaviour?

Comment: Do you have a screenshot of the table structure? That would show us what is going on.

Comment: Who knows, why bother? If you want the result in the ID order, use ORDER BY. Never, ever build an application depending on an "assumed" order.

Comment: @2766 there is no way of knowing why and its not relevant as its the way SQL Server works... unless you specify order by, you get random... which is some cases (enough to maybe make you think its always the case) is the insertion order.

Comment: @jarlh I just think it's a little weird to just suddenly be in non-order like that

Comment: @2766 it *could* be because SQL Server split a page and moved stuff around on the disk... thats the thing, you are saying the inner workings of SQL Server are weird without actually knowing what its doing under the hood. Nor should you know what goes on under the hood... PS your added screenshots don't change anything, other than to make your question very long.

Comment: @DaleK I added them because someone asked me to  and it was just a general question that's all it didn't affect my code or anything .

Comment: duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10064532/the-order-of-a-sql-select-statement-without-order-by-clause

Answer (score -1):

The auto-incremented id is fine.  The issue is the query, which is presumably something like:

```
select *
from users;
```

This query has no `order by`.  Hence, the results can be returned *in any order*.  And the order can change from one row to the next.

To see the results in a particular order, you always need to include `order by` in the query.  This query may be generated by a tool, so you have no control over that.

In practice, I would expect the results on a small table to be in the order of the clustered index.  Let me emphasize that this is not guaranteed, but is often the case.  So, if a different column is declared as the primary key or explicitly as the clustered index, then the ordering might *appear to be* by that column.

Answer (score -2):

I think ID is not the primary key. If you can make ID as the primary key the row should come in the correct order.

Comment: This answer is toitally incorrect. Unless there is an ORDER BY, you should not assume any particular order. On top of that, you are confusing primary key and clustering key.