# SQL - select specific results

Tags: sql, select

I have a table containing 2 columns for example. First column has unique values and the second column duplicates. Is there any way for me to select the first unique value only from the first column in relation to the second column?

For example: The results should get: Apple, Tire, and Fork only since they are the first results of the second column (category)

| Details | Category |
| --- | --- |
| Apple | Fruits |
| Banana | Fruits |
| Tire | Car |
| Engine | Car |
| Fork | Silverware |
| Spoon | Silverware |
| Knife | Silverware |

Comment: The problem with this statement `first results` is that there is no clear sort condition. For instance `Apple` is the _first_ for `Fruits` if we sort fruits alphnumerically, but `Tire` is not, if we sort the `Details` column then `Engine` would be first. If we do no sort at all, then the result is _non repeatable_ have a look at discussions like this one https://stackoverflow.com/q/10064532/1690217

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually we can use windowing functions like [ROW_NUMBER()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to simplify these types of queries, however your requested record set does not have a natural sort order that could be used that would result in the output you are expecting.

The following is a simple solution that uses `ROW_NUMBER()`, however it will not result as you have requested:

```
SELECT Category, Details
FROM
(
  SELECT Category, Details, row_number() over (partition by category order by details) as rn 
  FROM SpecificResults
) as numberedRecords
WHERE rn = 1;
```

Results:

| Category | Details |
| --- | --- |
| Car | **Engine** |
| Fruits | Apple |
| Silverware | Fork |

> You requested an output of: Apple, **Tire**, and Fork

The next query *might* produce the expected output, because we **do not** specify the sort, however due to this the output is **non-deterministic**, that is we cannot gaurantee it, due to database internals over time or even after instantaneously repeated queries the result *might* be different.

> There are many discussions on *non-deterministic* queries in SQL, have a read through this thread on SO: [The order of a SQL Select statement without Order By clause](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10064532/1690217)

```
SELECT Category, details.Details 
FROM SpecificResults byCategory
CROSS APPLY (
  SELECT TOP 1 Details
  FROM SpecificResults lookup
  WHERE lookup.Category = byCategory.Category
  --ORDER BY Details
) as details
GROUP BY Category, details.Details;
```

Results in:

| Category | Details |
| --- | --- |
| Car | **Tire** |
| Fruits | Apple |
| Silverware | Fork |

I have setup a SQL Fiddle for you to explore this further:  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/68530/12

---

## Real World Solution

In the real world, your dataset will have a primary key, and in many cases that key value might be incrementally tallied, if not there may be other columns that could be used to determine the sort order that will match your expected results.

Assuming that your dataset has an integer column called `Id` and that column is an Identity column, then a simple change to the original query using `ROW_NUMBER()` will achieve the desired result:

```
SELECT Category, Details
FROM
(
  SELECT Category, Details, row_number() over (partition by category order by Id) as rn 
  FROM OrderedResults
) as numberedRecords
WHERE rn = 1;
```

I have updated the SQL Fiddle with this variation: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/3f7bd/2

If there is a *Created date* or some other *Timestamp* or *DateTime* based column in your recordset then you you could consider those as candidates for your `ORDER BY` clause.

Comment: Nicely explained, considered all possibilities with quite a depth. I was far away from this kind of thinking. 

Answer (score 2):

SQL table represent *unordered* sets.  There is no "first" value unless a column specifies the value.  If you have such a column, then you can use `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by category order by <ordering col>) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

If you don't have such a column, then you simply cannot ask such a question in a relational database.  The data doesn't support the question.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand it correctly, try this -

`select category, details from ( select *, row number() over (partition by category order by details) as rn from tablename) where rn = 1`

Comment: `Tire` is not the first in that ordering, as mentioned in @ChrisSchaller 's comment

Comment: You are right, @Charlieface. Thanks for pointing that out. I ignored it because question was ambiguous about sort order. But, I liked other response. Upvoted it. 