# Django Table forward fill missing values

Tags: django, django-models

I have a table like this:

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| a | row |
|  | row |
|  | row |
|  | row |
| b | row |
|  | row |
|  | row |
| c | row |
| ... | .... |

How can I fill in missing values like forward fill in Pandas data frame using Django ORM query?

PS: I have an ID column which is unique

Comment: The question, as stated, is ambiguous. Because [the order of rows in an SQL table is ambiguous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10064532/the-order-of-a-sql-select-statement-without-order-by-clause), you need to specify a column to sort by (e.g. the primary key).

Comment: Hi @NickODell, I'm new to so and don't know how to add third column to my table, but I have an ID column that is PK

Comment: In that case, you can use `.order_by('id')` in your queryset to put the results in order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming, that the table is sorted by primary key.

If this is just a one-off you could do something like this. It will probably take a very long time if you have a very large table.
To actually run in you can use the django shell or [django management command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/custom-management-commands/).

```py
latest_a = None
max_id = MyModel.objects.last().id

for i in range(1, max_id + 1):
    try:
        instance = MyModel.objects.get(pk=i)
    except MyModel.DoesNotExist:
        continue
    if instance.a == None and latest_a:
        instance.a = latest_a
        instance.save()
    else:
        latest_a = instance.a
```