# Will mysql follows any default sorting option in innodb

Tags: mysql, innodb

I need to fetch data in batch wise. Example 1 to 1000, 1001 to 2000

Query: Select * from Employee limit 1, 1000
Select * from Employee limit 1001, 1000

Here no order by is used in this query. Will the second query returns duplicate data? or it will follow any sorting techniques?

Comment: you don't know.

Comment: see: [LIMIT Query Optimization](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/limit-optimization.html)

Comment: That is a bad "duplicate" link -- it refers to engines other than MySQL.  However, the effect is "correct".  That is, you must use `ORDER BY`; do not assume the table is in some order.

Answer (score 1):

This question was previously called a "duplicate" of [The order of a SQL Select statement without Order By clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10064532/the-order-of-a-sql-select-statement-without-order-by-clause) .  That is inappropriate as a "duplicate" link because it refers to engines other than MySQL. However, the effect is "correct". That is, you must use ORDER BY; do not assume the table is in some order.

I brought this question back to life because of a more subtle part of the question, referring to a common cause of duplicates.

This

```
Select * from Employee limit 1001, 1000
```

has two problems:

- `LIMIT` without an `ORDER BY` is asking for trouble (as discussed in the link)
- You appear to be doing "pagination" and you mentioned "returns duplicate data".  I bring this up because you can get dups *even if you have an `ORDER BY`*.  To elaborate...

`OFFSET` is implemented by stepping over rows.

Between getting N rows and getting the next N rows, some rows could be `INSERTed` or `DELETEd` in the 'previous' rows.  This messes up the `OFFSET`,  leading to either "duplicate" or "missing" rows.

More discussion, plus an alternative to `OFFSET`:  [*Pagination*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/Pagination)  It involves "remembering where you left off".

Specific to InnoDB:

- The data's BTree is ordered by the `PRIMARY KEY`.  That is predictable, *but*
- The query *does not necessarily* use the "table" to fetch the rows.  It might use a 'covering' `INDEX`, whose BTree is sorted by a secondary key!

For grins... MyISAM:

- The data is initially ordered by when the rows were inserted.
- That order may change as Inserts and Deletes, and even Updates, occur.
- And the query may use a covering index (Primary or secondary).